# What is the right Python annotation for imported method as variable?

Tags: python, typing

I'm looking for a `Method` type that I could use to annotate imported instance methods, since `Callable[[Self, ...], ...]` doesn't works.

Example:

**mod_method.py**

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from class import Object


def meth_method(self: Object, val: int) -> float:
    return val + 10.5
```

**class.py**

```py
from mod_method import meth_method


class Object:
    method: Method[[int], float] = meth_method
```

Answer (score 2):

`meth_method` is an ordinary function. An instance method in the sense you are thinking is just a function-valued class attribute. You get a method (of type `types.MethodType`) when you access the attribute via an instance of the class, thanks to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

As such, the correct type hint is `types.FunctionType`. (Not simply `Callable`, because it's `types.FunctionType.__get__` that produces the bound method.)

```
class Object:
    method: types.FunctionType = meth_method
```

`FunctionType` is not generic the way `Callable` is, so unfortunately you cannot be more specific, like `types.FunctionType[[Object, int], float]`.

---

As an aside, I would recommend against piecing a class definition together from functions defined outside the module. You may have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to properly annotate types.FunctionType?

Comment: Not specifically, but I'm curious about the use-case where you think this is necessary.

Comment: OK, I'm going to update the question.